# Circular dependencies in CommonJS singelton modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, circular-dependency, commonjs

I am wondering if and how the following is possible:

CommonJS environment, modules for use in node and/or browser (with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)).

Two (or more) modules, each returning a singelton needs to be available in different parts/modules of the application. They should also be able to call each other, so there is a circular dependency case. I know it is possible with some sort of dependency injection, but I want to avoid a code structure where I need to call something like *this.dependencies.ModuleName* when calling methods on one of theese singeltons from the other ones. I want to be able to call methods directly on the objects returned by the require-statements.

I realize this is not possible directly by two CommonJS modules exporting instanciated singelton objects (because of the circular dependencies). So I hope it will be possible to wrap it using a common code doing some magic. Something like:

```
var Magic = require('./magic');

module.exports = Magic.createSingelton({
   // ...
});
```

Browserify example that fails due to circular dependencies:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

var a = require('./class-a'),
    b = require('./class-b');

a.printSomething();
b.printSomething();
},{"./class-a":2,"./class-b":3}],2:[function(require,module,exports){

var b = require('./class-b');


var A = function() {};

A.prototype = {
    printSomething: function() {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = document.querySelector('body').innerHTML + 'A got from B: ' + b.getSomething() + '<br />';
    },

    getSomething: function() {
        return 'FROM A';
    }
};

module.exports = new A();
},{"./class-b":3}],3:[function(require,module,exports){

var a = require('./class-a');


var B = function() {};

B.prototype = {
    printSomething: function() {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = document.querySelector('body').innerHTML + 'B got from A: ' + a.getSomething() + '<br />';
    },

    getSomething: function() {
        return 'FROM B';
    }
};

module.exports = new B();
},{"./class-a":2}]},{},[1]);
```

I know [RefluxJS](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) data stores are working this way. Actions can be called from outside the stores, or from one store to another. However there you have to create both an action module and a store module. Is some kind of structure like that required, or is it possible with one module per singelton like described above? Example code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, Foo is loaded before Bar and thus Bar can use Foo while it's loading, but Foo cannot use Bar while it's loading.

What I normally do is to create an init function (Foo.init, Bar.init) and call all init functions when ALL resources are done loading. In your example code this is not needed, because the functions you define in the exports are allowed to contain references to resources that are not yet loaded: as long as the functions are not being executed before the loading is complete.

Comment: It's not only while loading. If I call it in the application, even long after the page has loaded without errors, the same happens because the reference to the other object (when calling getSomething from the doSomething method in my example) was not available when the object was instanciated.

Comment: OH, that should not happen :O